How to compile the source code on GitHub into the files they release？
I'm sorry, I am a complete beginner. I made some changes to the source code of the GP2040-CE project (using ChatGPT), and now I'm trying to compile it into software for my device (a uf2 file as their releases). I've tried my best to search for information, but I just can't seem to get it done.
Project URL: https://github.com/OpenStickCommunity/GP2040-CE
I tried using cmake, it seemed successful, but no uf2 file was generated.

After running cmake, which configures a project, you need to run make, and, possibly, make install. If you have done all these steps, then [edit] the question post and add details about what exactly you have done.

Turns out there is an official document, I found it. Thanks anyway.

If you found an answer to your problem, kindly post it here so other users can benefit from your research. Self-answers are encouraged. You will be able to accept your answer after 48 hours.
